# What's gonna happen to those rows that don't have a corresponding foreign key if inserting after SET foreign_key_checks = 0;?

Tags: mysql, sql

Just learn there's a `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` setting from https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/, which is said to be useful when:

> Sometimes, it is very useful to disable foreign key checks e.g., when
> you import data from a CSV file into a table. If you don’t disable
> foreign key checks, you have to load data into a proper order i.e.,
> you have to load data into parent tables first and then child tables,
> which can be tedious. However, if you disable the foreign key checks,
> you can load data into tables in any order.

I tried it and it works. I insert some rows that don't have a corresponding foreign key value in the parent table.

So my question is: Will there be any problems if I keep these rows with nonexistent foreign key value?

As for now, after I `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`, nothing happened.

(I was thinking there might be some sort of reference intergrity check and errors pops up, but no).

So again, any other risks except those rows are corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Will there be any problems' - as far as db is concerned no , as far as your business is concerned only you can say, but be prepared for orphans and childless parents.

for example
order_header (id,dt,customer);
order_detail (id, order_id,product_id,quantity,price);

With no referential integrity you may lose who an order_detail pertains to and conversely you may end up with order_headers but no order_details. I would class this as a serious issue.
Losing referential integrity on product_id I would classify as less serious.

Comment: "as far as db is concerned no", ok that's what I want to know and thanks for the additional information.